# Get Google Drive link in Google Sheets when the name of the folder matches in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want guidance from the community regarding the below question.
If in Cell A1, I write Sam_123 then in Cell B1 the link of the folder named 'Sam_123' in Google Drive should appear.

The Path of the folder is as: "Name of the customers' -(folder Name) --> in it, folders are named date-wise --> in it there is a folder named "Sam_123".
The name of every folder is unique so the chances of duplicates are nill.

Is there any formula or script which can work(also, will that script work on an existing sheet or do I need to create a new one?)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I don't have any sample script. sorry.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Hi @Tanaike, I don't have any sample script. sorry.`. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to say. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Answer (score 1):

About `If in Cell A1, I write Sam_123 then in Cell B1 the link of the folder named 'Sam_123' in Google Drive should appear.`, in this case, I think that Drive service (DriveApp) is required to be used. But, in the current stage, DriveApp cannot be used with the custom function. So, in this case, how about using the OnEdit installable trigger? When the OnEdit installable trigger is used, when a value of `Sam_123` of the folder name is put to column "A", the folder ID is put to column "B" of the same row. When this is reflected in a sample Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and please set the variables of `sheetName` and `topFolderId`, and save the script. And, [please install OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

When you use this script, please put the value of `Sam_123` in column "A" of your expected sheet. By this, the script is run.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const topFolderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID of your top folder.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 1) return;
  const value = range.getValue();
  const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(topFolderId).getFoldersByName(value);
  range.offset(0, 1).setValue(folders.hasNext() ? folders.next().getId() : `Folder '${value}' was not found.`);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you directly run this script with the script editor, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for your in-depth explanation. Will try it and share the feedback with you.